# Docker & Laravel : configure: error: Package requirements (oniguruma) were not met

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile

Can anyone help me with this problem.

When i try to create a docker image from a dockerfile for laravel application i get this error:

> checking for oniguruma... no
>       configure: error: Package requirements (oniguruma) were not met:
>
> ```
> No package 'oniguruma' found
>
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
> installed software in a non-standard prefix.
>
> Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ONIG_CFLAGS
> and ONIG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
> See the pkg-config man page for more details.
> ```
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring' returned a non-zero code: 1

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring
WORKDIR /app
COPY app /app # this copies all the app files to a folder called `app`
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

and the docker command to build the Dockerfile

```
sudo docker build -t test .
```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Just remove `mbstring` from the `docker-php-ext-install` instruction.

The error is caused by a dependency problem - the `mbstring` extension requires the `oniguruma` library to make multibyte regular expression functions work. From the [installation guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php):

> Oniguruma is necessary for the regular expression functions with multibyte character support. Oniguruma is bundled with mbstring. As of PHP 5.4.0, if Oniguruma is already installed on the system, --with-onig[=DIR] can be specified to use the installed library.

However, in the image that you're using, the extension is already installed and configured, so you don't need to do anything else:

```
$> docker run --rm -it php:7 php -r "var_dump(mb_ereg_match('^99.*', '123456'));"                                                                                      
bool(false)

$> docker run --rm -it php:7 php -r "var_dump(mb_ereg_match('^12.*', '123456'));"                                                                                      
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 201):

What @kalatabe said is correct. But in case you absolutely wanted to make sure mbstring gets installed, you can also add `libonig-dev` to your `apt-get install`

Comment: ERROR: unable to select packages:
#5 1.441   libonig-dev (no such package):
#5 1.441     required by: world[libonig-dev]

Comment: I also had to add the 'libzip-dev' dependency to the apt-get install

Answer (score 3):

For **ALPINE**-based images e.g. `FROM php:8.0.24-fpm-alpine3.16`
you have to add the package `oniguruma-dev` like:

```
FROM php:8.0.24-fpm-alpine3.16
...
RUN apk update && apk add oniguruma-dev
...
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mbstring
...
```

As @katalabe & @kgx already mentioned:
mbstring requires any kind of oniguruma installed.

For Debian-based images please see @kgx answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59373581/6852290

Answer (score 2):

If your are using a distro with yum package manager. Execute this command:

```sh
sudo yum install -y oniguruma-devel
```

Comment: `Unable to locate package oniguruma-devel`

Comment: @4n70wa package oniguruma-devel is in epel repository

Answer (score 1):

**for [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew) user**

You can solve this error by removing the `mbstring` variant from the installation command using `-mbstring` parameter.

***Example:***

```bash
phpbrew install php-7.4 +default -mbstring
```

Answer (score 1):

On Centos 8:

```
$ yum install dnf-plugins-core
$ yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
$ yum install oniguruma-devel
```

This will install the required oniguruma library and satisfies dependency.

Answer (score 0):

On AlmaLinux 9 (el9 base):

```
dnf --enablerepo=crb install oniguruma-devel
```

Where CRB is CodeReady Linux Builder repository contains additional packages for use by developers.

For related information, visit:
[oniguruma-devel-6.9.6-1.el9.5.i686.rpm - Description](https://rockylinux.pkgs.org/9/rockylinux-crb-x86_64/oniguruma-devel-6.9.6-1.el9.5.i686.rpm.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).