# Upgrade from PHP 7.2 to PHP 7.4

Tags: php, linux, upgrade, redhat, php-7.4

I'm going to upgrade an existing application from PHP 7.2.11 to PHP 7.4.6 on linux Red Hat server,
Server cannot access Internet so I have to install PHP 7.4.6 manually. I downloaded the source code of PHP 7.4.6 then I run the command

```
'./configure' '--prefix=/logi/php746' '--bindir=/logi/php746/bin'
 '--with-config-file-path=/logi/php746' 
'--with-apxs2=/logi/http2223/bin/apxs' '--with-pear' 
'--enable-dom' 
'--enable-simplexml' '--enable-calendar=shared' 
'--enable-sockets=shared' '--enable-soap=shared'
 '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--enable-sysvsem' 
'--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sysvmsg' 
'--enable-ftp=shared' '--enable-sqlite-utf8'
 '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-zip=shared' 
'--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-dba=shared'
 '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/logi/php746/external-libs/sqlite'
 '--with-sqlite=shared'
 '--with-sqlite3=shared,/logi/php746/external-libs/sqlite'
 '--with-cdb' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--with-zlib=shared,/logi/php746/external-libs/zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/logi/php746/external-libs/zlib' 
'--with-libxml-dir=/logi/php746/external-libs/libxml2' 
'--with-iconv=shared,/logi/php746/external-libs/libiconv'
 '--with-iconv-dir=/logi/php746/external-libs/libiconv' 
'--with-openssl=shared,/logi/php746/external-libs/ssl'
 '--with-openssl-dir=/logi/php746/external-libs/ssl'
 '--with-curl=shared,/logi/php746/external-libs/curl' 
'--with-ldap=shared,/logi/php746/external-libs/openldap' 
'--with-png-dir=/logi/php746/external-libs/libpng'
 '--with-freetype-dir=/logi/php746/external-libs/freetype'
 '--with-pgsql=shared,/logi/php746/external-libs/postgresql'
 '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/logi/php746/external-libs/postgresql' 
'--with-mm=/logi/php746/external-libs/mm' 
'--with-gettext=shared,/logi/php746/external-libs/gettext' 
'--with-db4=/logi/php746/external-libs/db' 
'--with-mcrypt=shared,/logi/php746/external-libs/libmcrypt'
 '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--with-libexpat-dir=/logi/php746/external-libs/expat'
```

I get the error

```
   configure: error: Package requirements (oniguruma) were not met:
    
    No package 'oniguruma' found
    
    Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
    installed software in a non-standard prefix.
    
    Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ONIG_CFLAGS
    and ONIG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
    See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I didn't get this error when I installed php 7.2

How can I fix the error without using `yum install PACKAGE_NAME`? THANKS.

Comment: What's the exact restriction here? Installing packages from the network or installing pre-compiled binaries?

Comment: when I tried to install php 7.4 I get the error configure: error: Package requirements (oniguruma) were not met:

Comment: while I didn't get this error when I installed php 7.2

Comment: Acording to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251008/docker-laravel-configure-error-package-requirements-oniguruma-were-not-m#answer-59253249) you need to remove mbstring extension. Try to remove this line `'--enable-mbstring=shared'` and re run the command.

Comment: but I need mbstring extension

Comment: install [oniguruma](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/oniguruma-6.8.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) then. You are missing dependency which is blocking installation process.

Comment: You get that error when you try to **compile** PHP from source code. Compiling from source code is one of the possible methods. You can also build from source code packages (`.src.rpm`) or install compiled packages (`.rpm`). In all cases, you can download from the internet, copy to a DVD or pendrive, etc. All I'm saying is that we don't know what exact things you aren't allowed to do and perhaps you're going the hard way without needing to.

Comment: big thanks @SergeyLigus & Álvaro González